# Catching error thrown by connect-mongostore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, error-handling

I have a node app balanced across two servers that uses MongoLab for its session storage. However, recently we've been experiencing some intermittent drop outs in connectivity to MongoLab, which causes said connect-mongostore to throw the following error and never recover:

```
/node_modules/connect-mongostore/lib/connect-mongostore.js:80
  if (err) throw new Error('Error connecting to database:\n' + err.message
                 ^
Error: Error connecting to database:
failed to connect to [ds031681.mongolab.com:31681]
Error: failed to connect to [ds031681.mongolab.com:31681]
```

I'm using the following code to initialise the sessions:

```
var session          = require('express-session'),
MongoStore       = require('connect-mongostore')(session);

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({
   host: 'ds031681.mongolab.com',
   port: '31681',
   db: 'sessions',
   username: 'username',
   password: 'password'
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    store: sessionStore,
    autoReconnect: true,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    ssl: true
}));
```

I am really struggling to find a way to catch this error so I can retry the connection, or at the very least restart the app. It seems the autoReconnect option doesn't reconnect from this type of failure. Every subsequent request returns the error: `Error: no open connections`.

I've tried adding:

```
sessionStore.on('error', function(err){
   console.log(err);
});
```

But it seems this doesn't do anything. Obviously try catch blocks won't work, and it seems putting middleware into a domain doesn't work either. Can anyone help me catch this error so I can handle it appropriately please?

Thanks

Oh and ideally, I'd like to be able to do this without having to wait for someone to try and connect, so it can recognise when a connection has dropped and reconnect in the background.

Comment: same issue here, did you solve it?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue. Did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't even remember asking this question in all honesty. 
From what I do remember, we stopped using that mongo module in the end. And we moved away from MongoLab.